# Errors in Oracle sample scripts

Tags: oracle

I want to create a sample schema Sales History (SH) provided by Oracle.
So I visited the site

Sample Models and Scripts:
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/datamodeler/sample-models-scripts-224531.html

and downloaded the SQL script from
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/datamodeler/shsql-167694.zip

But I noticed that it couldn't be executed without errors. First I had to create a tablespace EXAMPLE, then I had to fix the order of PARTITION elements in the script etc. Do they mention some preliminary work that has to be done before running the script?

Anyway, after all the error correction work I have only 2 errors now.

The first one:

```
Error starting at line : 2 290 in command -
CREATE DIMENSION PRODUCTS_DIM 
    LEVEL CATEGORY IS PRODUCTS.PROD_CATEGORY_ID 
    LEVEL SUBCATEGORY IS PRODUCTS.PROD_SUBCATEGORY_ID 
    LEVEL PRODUCT IS PRODUCTS.PROD_ID 
    LEVEL PROD_TOTAL IS PRODUCTS.PROD_TOTAL_ID 
    HIERARCHY PROD_ROLLUP ( 
        PRODUCT  CHILD OF  
        SUBCATEGORY  CHILD OF  
        CATEGORY  CHILD OF  
        PROD_TOTAL 
    ) 
    ATTRIBUTE Attr12 LEVEL CATEGORY DETERMINES ( 
        PROD_CATEGORY , 
        PROD_CATEGORY_DESC 
    ) 
    ATTRIBUTE Attr13 LEVEL SUBCATEGORY DETERMINES ( 
        PROD_SUBCATEGORY , 
        PROD_SUBCATEGORY_DESC 
    ) 
    ATTRIBUTE Attr14 LEVEL PRODUCT DETERMINES ( 
        PROD_NAME , 
        PROD_MIN_PRICE , 
        PROD_LIST_PRICE , 
        PROD_STATUS , 
        PROD_PACK_SIZE , 
        PROD_UNIT_OF_MEASURE , 
        PROD_WEIGHT_CLASS , 
        PROD_DESC 
    ) 
    ATTRIBUTE Attr15 LEVEL PROD_TOTAL DETERMINES 
        PROD_TOTAL 
    ATTRIBUTE Attr16 LEVEL CATEGORY DETERMINES 
        PROMO_CATEGORY 
    ATTRIBUTE Attr19 LEVEL SUBCATEGORY DETERMINES 
        PROMO_SUBCATEGORY
Error report -
ORA-00904: "PRODUCTS"."PROMO_SUBCATEGORY": 
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

The table PROMOTIONS has been created successfully

```
CREATE TABLE PROMOTIONS 
    ( 
     PROMO_ID NUMBER (6)  NOT NULL , 
     PROMO_NAME VARCHAR2 (30 BYTE)  NOT NULL , 
     PROMO_SUBCATEGORY VARCHAR2 (30 BYTE)  NOT NULL , 
     PROMO_SUBCATEGORY_ID NUMBER  NOT NULL , 
     PROMO_CATEGORY VARCHAR2 (30 BYTE)  NOT NULL , 
     PROMO_CATEGORY_ID NUMBER  NOT NULL , 
     PROMO_COST NUMBER (10,2)  NOT NULL , 
     PROMO_BEGIN_DATE DATE  NOT NULL , 
     PROMO_END_DATE DATE  NOT NULL , 
     PROMO_TOTAL VARCHAR2 (15 BYTE)  NOT NULL , 
     PROMO_TOTAL_ID NUMBER  NOT NULL 
    ) LOGGING 
    MONITORING 
;
```

And the second one:

```
Error starting at line : 2 548 in command -
CREATE TABLE SALES_TRANSACTIONS_EXT 
    ( 
    PROD_ID NUMBER (22) (22) (22) , 
    CUST_ID NUMBER (22) (22) (22) , 
    TIME_ID DATE (7) (7) (7) , 
    CHANNEL_ID NUMBER (22) (22) (22) , 
    PROMO_ID NUMBER (22) (22) (22) , 
    QUANTITY_SOLD NUMBER (22) (22) (22) , 
    AMOUNT_SOLD NUMBER (10, 2) (10,  2) (10,  2) , 
    UNIT_COST NUMBER (10, 2) (10,  2) (10,  2) , 
    UNIT_PRICE NUMBER (10, 2) (10,  2) (10,  2) 
    ) 
    ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL 
    ( 
    TYPE oracle_loader 
    ACCESS PARAMETERS 
    USING CLOB RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE CHARACTERSET US7ASCII 
 TERRITORY AMERICAN 
 BADFILE log_file_dir:'ext_1v3.bad' 
 LOGFILE log_file_dir:'ext_1v3.log' 
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY "|" OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY ' ' LDRTRIM 
 ( PROD_ID         , 
 CUST_ID         , 
 TIME_ID         DATE(10) "YYYY-MM-DD", 
 CHANNEL_ID      , 
 PROMO_ID        , 
 QUANTITY_SOLD   , 
 AMOUNT_SOLD     , 
 UNIT_COST       , 
 UNIT_PRICE 
 ) 
    LOCATION ( 'sale1v3.dat' ) 
    ) 
    REJECT LIMIT 100
Error report -
ORA-00907: 
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

DbVisualizer underlined the second `"(22)"` in the line `" PROD_ID NUMBER (22) (22) (22) , "` but I still cannot figure out where I should place the right parenthesis.

I'm not familiar with Oracle specific SQL.

Below is the full script after all my corrections
http://denis-aristov.ucoz.com/unsorted/SH.sql

And the full error output:
http://denis-aristov.ucoz.com/unsorted/SH_errors.txt

Comment: Get the official ddl and data loading scripts here. https://github.com/oracle/db-sample-schemas/tree/master/sales_history you'll need sqlldr for the data

Comment: @thatjeffsmith Thanks. I've tried it, but without success. Lots of errors. Could I do something wrong during installation of Oracle 18c? Asking because one of my coleagues has installed 11g and all the schemas are already installed.

Comment: start a new question, share your steps and the errors, then we can help